# alignment issue in a bootstrap form

Tags: forms, layout, twitter-bootstrap

having an issue with a drop-down aligning correctly in a form that I've created in Bootstrap:

https://www.box.net/shared/h6yailsigchqndexdieo

it's indenting over for some reason and I'm not sure how to correct it.

context for the form is that it appears in an iframe like this:

```
<iframe class="span9 borderless" src="{app name}">
```

additionally, there's an alignment issue between the drop-down and the buttons next to it. context for that looks like this:

```
<form action="/{action}" method="GET">

    <select name="{name}">
        <option data-id="1" ... >...</option> 
        ...
    </select>  

    <button type="submit" value="{value}" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="icon-chevron-down icon-white"></i> {name of button} </button>
    <a class="btn btn-inverse" style="color:#FFF" href="{link}"><i class="icon-edit icon-white"></i> {name}</a> 
    <a class="btn btn-success" href="{link}"><i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i> {name}</a>

</form>
```

Any additional thoughts why these might be misaligned?

Comment: never mind, looks like a css issue

Answer (score 0):

`<form action="/{action}" method="GET" class="form-inline">` 
adding the "form-inline" class to the form tag will fix this.